# Johnny-cache and taggit-tags

Tags: django, django-johnny-cache

I'm using johnny-cache (1.6.1a) and Django 1.6 for a project.

I have a model that implements TaggableManger:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    editor = models.ForeignKey(Employee, blank=True, null=True=)
    ....
    keywords = TaggableManager('Keywords', blank=True)
```

The keywords were not getting invalidated automatically by johnny-cache. So I used a post_save signal to do it.

I tried passing the object names, e.g., `invalidate('Tag')`, but it never worked.

This does:

```
def johhny_clear_cache(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if sender.__name__ in ['Tag', 'Publication']:
        johnny.cache.invalidate('taggit_taggeditem', 'taggit_tag')
```

So I'm wondering if this is the expected behavior, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use johnny-cache, it’s broken with Django >= 1.6. Use [django-cachalot](https://github.com/BertrandBordage/django-cachalot) instead :)